# Unable to connect from a different network express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, networking

I'm experimenting with node.js and express.js.

When I try to connect to my web server from any computer in my network, it works, but then when I try to connect from outside network the connection times out.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello World");
});
http.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000!");
});
```

Comment: Use a *code sample* instead of a *JS/html/css snippet* when the code can't be executed on SO.

Comment: @EmileBergeron sorry thank you

Comment: You probably just need to open the port 3000 from your router admin interface, and maybe forward it to the server.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I forwarded my router to port 3000, is that the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your code and I'm able to access the server from outside my local network by navigating to:

http://173.0.[my].[ip]:3000

So the code is correct. It could be that you need to open the port `3000` to the outside world. Here's how it can be accomplished.

## Through your router admin interface

Here's mine for example:

[image: Single port forwarding]

Where **192.168.1.130** is the local IP of the PC I'm running the http server on.

Don't forget to click the **Save settings** button in that interface to apply the changes.

## Using a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) (mentioned by [eddiezane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39440366/1218980))

Install ngrok through their website or without leaving the command prompt, with the ngrok node wrapper.

```
npm install ngrok -g
```

Start your http server and then run:

```
ngrok http 3000
```

Navigate to one of the url in front of `Forwarding`:

[image: ngrok http forward port 3000]

The free version is more for a quick test and less as a definitive way to expose a service in a production environnement since every time you restart ngrok, a new [user-hostile](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=user-hostile) url is given to you.

## Other possible problems

- It could also be that you need to add an exception to the firewall (if on windows).

Comment: Why did you use port 8888, should I use 3000 for mine?

Comment: @MooShoeGaming I updated the image to reflect the exact change needed

Comment: @MooShoeGaming best thanks on SO is to accept an answer!

Answer (score 1):

To add to Emile's answer, I would check out [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) which is an awesome tool that generates you a publicly accessible URL for a port on your local machine.

Here's a good [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html) on it my buddy wrote.

Comment: That you! That was really helpful!